# Design Bechmarking

Tags: java, database, service

I have table named Employee with id,first name, middle name, last name as fields. They have their preferences stored in another table. Each employee details are fetched using java services. Every employee can see other employee information. Consider there are employees A,B,C,and D. The employee can set display name preference as first,middle, last or last,middle,first. If the employee A sets his display format as first,middle,last as a preference then all the search results of the other employees should be in the preferred format. So we thought we would fetch the results, and apply preferences in service.

Another option would be to apply preferences in another table so the preferences table would have two columns, one with each  preference. So directly the results are fetched from the preference.

Which is the best approach?

Comment: Do the preferences include other things as well or just the display name preference?

Comment: How does "Bechmarking" come into this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to consider just the preference of displaying the names in different orders i.e. `one preference`, the `first approach` would do pretty good.

The `second approach` (normalization) would be useful in case of one `user setting multiple preferences (one-to-many relationship)` such as name preference, preference of columns to display, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the **former one** is a better solution if the `preferences` only affect the fields display order of the search result. However, I suggest you to have a second thought about the responbility of the `preferences`. IMHO, java service should pass it to the web layer directly if the `perferences` is just taken as metadata for view. Then some components in the web layer take over the `perferences` and do the corresponding display logic. May be I made the whole thing complicated...

About the second approach, it's not that suitable for your scenario for it's bad for extensibility. If something more need to show up in the `perferences`, you will have to alter the table to add the necessary columns. I think TechSpellBound is right, creating a **one-to-many relation** between `Employee` and `preferences` will be good.